# C# Optimise HTTP requests performance in critical apps

Tags: c#, http, network-programming, httprequest

I'm working on a critical c# console application that heavily uses network (HTTP). Due to the criticality of the application, it must report some events via HTTP very quickly. How can I optimize and achieve fast HTTP connections?

I'm starting with this settings:

```
internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
            ServicePointManager.EnableDnsRoundRobin = true;
            ServicePointManager.ReusePort = true;
            ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 0, 0);
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 13000;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main way to realistically achieve better performance here is multi threading.

In network you often can't actually change how long you will have to wait. So let as many threads start to wait as soon as possible.
Meaning: Request everything as soon as possible.

In practice this often goes as far as speculative loading based on estimates and statistics, or even brute force For example:
It is common browser behavior to start loading pages *before* you have click on any link.